# Forecasting with ARIMA and xreg in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm having trouble with my first forecasting implementation in R. What I'd like to achieve is to predict the variable Y with 2 exogenous variables X1 and X2. The 3 datasets are each represented as a single column with 12 rows.

From another [Stackpost](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41070/how-to-setup-xreg-argument-in-auto-arima-in-r) I followed a similar approach:

```
DataSample <- data.frame(Y=Y[,1],Month=rep(1:12,1),
                     X1=X1[,1],X2=X2[,1])

predictor_matrix <- cbind(Month=model.matrix(~as.factor(DataSample$Month)), 
                          X1=DataSample$X1,
                          X2=DataSample$X2)
# Remove intercept
predictor_matrix <- predictor_matrix[,-1]

# Rename columns
colnames(predictor_matrix) <- c("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","X1","X2")

# Variable to be modeled
var <- ts(DataSample$Y, frequency=12)

#Find ARIMA
modArima <- auto.arima(var, xreg = predictor_matrix)
```

At this line I get the following error:

> Error in optim(init[mask], armaCSS, method = optim.method, hessian =
>   FALSE,  :    non-finite value supplied by optim

I presume that my `predictor_matrix` is not in the correct format but I can't find the error.

Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indicated "datasets are ... 12 rows". Your predictor matrix has 13 columns (11 months [of dummy variables?] and 2 other variables). Therefore, you necessarily have a linear dependence among the columns and the optimization procedure fails.

You need (ideally much) more data to support the number of predictor variables and/or a sparser set of predictors.

Comment: That was indeed the problem, I was using an example of a bigger data-set. Is there a rule of thumb how many datasets needed per added predictor?

Comment: The rules of thumb vary by field, but in economics you might aim for at least 4 times the number of predictors, given a strong pre-fit theory for the reasonableness of the variables. In other fields, you'd be expected to have much more data, e.g. 8x rather than 4x, e.g. psychology where the significance of variables might be tenuous to begin with.